# Three.js multiplyQuaternions function

Tags: javascript, three.js, sensors, quaternions

I have some Inertial Measurement Units (IMUs) and I was trying to get the relative rotation of one with respect to another in quaternions. The way I expected it to work was as below:

```
//First IMU
quat[0] = new THREE.Quaternion(quaternion[0]["x"],quaternion[0]["y"],quaternion[0]["z"],quaternion[0]["w"]).normalize();

if (calibrationimu[0] && quat[0].x!=0){
     referenceimu[0].copy(quat[0]);
     referenceimu[0].conjugate();
     fingercalibrationimu[0] = false;
 }
initialrel[0] = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (referenceimu[0], quat[0]).normalize();
initialrel[0].conjugate();

//Second IMU
quat[1] = new THREE.Quaternion(quaternion[1]["x"],quaternion[1]["y"],quaternion[1]["z"],quaternion[1]["w"]).normalize();

if (calibrationimu[1] && quat[1].x!=0){
    referenceimu[1].copy(quat[1]);
    calibrationimu[1] = false;
    referenceimu[1].conjugate();
}
initialrel[1] = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (referenceimu[1], quat[1]).normalize();     
finalrel[0] = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (initialrel[0], initialrel[1]).normalize();
```

That didn't work for some reason, and during my desperation I was trying random things and it works almost as wanted as below:

```
//First IMU
quat[0] = new THREE.Quaternion(quaternion[0]["x"],quaternion[0]["y"],quaternion[0]["z"],quaternion[0]["w"]).normalize();

if (calibrationimu[0]&&quat[0].x!=0){
    referenceimu[0].copy(quat[0]);
    referenceimu[0].conjugate();
    calibrationimu[0] = false;
    }
fingerinitialrel[0] = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (referenceimu[0], quat[0]).normalize();

initialrel[0].conjugate();


//Second IMU 
quat[1] = new THREE.Quaternion(quaternion[1]["x"],quaternion[1]["y"],quaternion[1]["z"],quaternion[1]["w"]).normalize();
quat[1] = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (quat[0], quat[1], quat[0].conjugate()).normalize();
if (calibrationimu[1] && quat[1].x!=0){
    referenceimu[1].copy(quat[1]);
    calibrationimu[1] = false;
    referenceimu[1].conjugate();
    }

finalrel[0] = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (referenceimu[1], quat[1]).normalize();
```

And despite the fact that I don't have the slightest why this does anything meaningful, I noticed that:

```
q0 = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (q1, q2);
q0 = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (q0, q3);
```

doesn't give the same results as:

```
q0 = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (q1, q2, q3);
```

despite the fact that quaternion multiplication is assiciative.
As fas as the documentation of THREE.js is concerned the multiplyQuaternions() function takes only 2 inputs, so I have no clue what it does with the 3rd one and why I don't get an error.

Any suggestion you may give me is much appreciated guys, I've been really stuck for a while now.

Comment: Javascript is very loosely typed, you can give a function an arbitary amount of values, and it takes them.

Comment: In otherwords, `q0 = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (q1, q2, q3);` is the same as `q0 = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (q1, q2);`

Comment: @Bálint No, as a matter of fact, it is not the same. tried it and for some reason:

`q0 = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (q1, q2, q3);`

is different than both:

`q0 = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (q1, q2);`

and 

`q0 = new THREE.Quaternion().multiplyQuaternions (q2, q3);`